# A VB.NET equivalent of a PHP hash function

Tags: php, vb.net, hash, sha256

I am having trouble converting this PHP code to VB.

```
$hashpw = hash('sha256', $salt.$password.$salt)
```

I have this VB code

```
Public Function HashPassword(ByVal Password As String, ByVal Salt As String) As String
    Dim pwd As String = Salt & Password & Salt
    Dim hasher As New Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed()
    Dim pwdb As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pwd)
    Dim pwdh As Byte() = hasher.ComputeHash(pwdb)
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(pwdh)
End Function
```

but it seems that the password I retrieve from the database is not equivalent to the returned value from the VB code above. The password was encrypted using the PHP code above.

Can anyone help me with this?
Very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php hash function returns the data encoded in hexadecimal not base64.

```
Return BitConverter.ToString(pwdh).Replace("-", "")
```